# HTML - why some elements have > instead of />?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

let's look at bootstrap resources:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

sometimes I see `<input type="file">` and many more other tags.

What's the reason of not closing HTML tags with `/>` ?

Comment: Because `/>` doesn't mean what you think it means in HTML, and in HTML5, it's quite redundant.

Comment: To my understanding both notations are allowed by the html specification. Some people use /> to make their code 'clean' and others do not to save bytes. Personally I belong to group 2.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_soup

Comment: @BoltClock: Actually, I wouldn't say "redundant", but "dangerous". `<textarea/><p>caption</p>` does something *very* different from what one'd imagine from experience with XML. (i.e. it's equivalent to `<textarea><p>caption</p></textarea>`)

Comment: @Amadan: Indeed - it is redundant at the very least for its intended uses, dangerous in anything else.

Comment: Cause `<link>invalid</link>` so hey let's just `<link>` or `<link />` (as you want). Than we have `<script>valid code</script>`, but we have also `<script src="js.js">` so let's make it: `<script></script>` but let's also make this invalid: `<script src="js.js">invalid</script>`. Now, `<input>invalid</input>` so simply `<input>` or `<input />` as you like. `<button>` needs the text node so: `<button>OK</button>` *to be continued...* :) note also that HTML5 is less strict so no need to use `/` in `<img>` and other self-closing tags as `<input>`.

Comment: Let's reformulate my earlier statement based on the tag_soup link: Several HTML specification versions came out with several contradicting rules. And now for the sake of compatibility all those are supported. There are a couple of mine fields as Roko C. Buljan pointed out. But then there are still open options, eg. for <BR> VS <BR />. In such cases optimization best cases would point into the direction of selecting the lean version.

Answer (score 1):

They are called self-closing tag or singleton tag. Here is the list of tags you can use it as self-closing.

```
<area />
<base />
<br />
<col />
<command />
<embed />
<hr />
<img />
<input />
<keygen />
<link />
<meta />
<param />
<source />
<track />
<wbr />
```

Comment: [Void elements](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/syntax.html#void-elements) And to welcome you to the magnificent world of HTML5 you don't need to use the `/` for any of them.

Comment: They are known as [void elements](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/#self-closing-tag): "The self-closing tag syntax may be used" ... but it is **not** necessary. It's a personal choice thing :)

Comment: Does not answer the questions asked.